# HTTP Status 405 - JSPs only permit GET POST or HEAD

Tags: jsp, tomcat, exception, tomcat8

Since JSP 2.3 (Tomcat 8) only supported method for JSP is GET POST or HEAD:

https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr245/245-MR3.html
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServlet.java?view=diff&r1=1497877&r2=1497878&pathrev=1497878

But, I suppose, it is a big incompatible change as, for example, for exception handler it is used to forward to JSP for rendering exception and iso JSP view since JSP 2.3 response is:

```
Method Not Allowed
HTTP Status 405 - JSPs only permit GET POST or HEAD 

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
```

If we use REST and Spring HandlerExceptionResolver in case of exception we bump into this problem for sure. Are there any workaround for this problem (iso change http method type)?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, there is no workaround (at the moment) for this. My recommendation to the EG was that the handled methods were made configurable. That suggestion was rejected. I suggest you raise this specific issue with them since it is a good argument for making the supported methods configurable on a per JSP (or group of JSPs) basis.

Meanwhile, I'll take a look at making this configurable using some form of Tomcat specific configuration under the bug you raised for this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56568

UPDATE: As of Tomcat 8.0.9 when a JSP is used to generate an error page, any HTTP method will be allowed.

Comment: when was this change made? how long have PUT requests been denied for jsps?

Comment: The JSP 2.3 specification requires JSPs to respond to GET, HEAD and POST only. The behaviour for all other HTTP methods is undefined. Tomcat opted to reject them to protect against HTTP verb tampering attacks. Since this is JSP 2.3, the change applies to Tomcat 8 onwards.

Comment: How to specify JSP error page in order to redirect work?
I'm using Tomcat 8.0.9

Comment: If you redirect to an error page (rather than using the error handling mechanism) you'll need to set isErrorPage="true" and wait for 8.0.12 to be released.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed by @MarkThomas you can make any `HTTP` request if you declare your JSP page as `errorPage` like this
[image]

If you don't want to do that then there is one more alternative
1. Create a filter (if you directly want to call a `JSP` page) or create a servlet (which will eventually call `JSP` page)
2. Do this in doFilter() or in case of servlet doPut()/doDelete()
[image]
Here I'm doing this in Filter where `request` is `ServletRequest` object.
I'm using `HttpRequestWrapper` to wrap the original request with a fake request and telling it to return **POST** for `DELETE` and `PUT` requests so `JSP` thinks its a `POST` request and the page is executed, only downside is you won't be able to tell what the original request was; this can also be covered if you set an attribute with original method name, like this

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
request.setAttribute("method", req.getMethod());
req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/resources/" +  resourceName + ".jsp").forward(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        String method = super.getMethod();
        if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("delete") || method.equalsIgnoreCase("put")) {
            return "POST";
        } else {
            return method;
        }
    }
}, response);
```