# POST of Spring edit form on Tomcat 8 fails with 405 while on tomcat 7 works

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat8, http-status-code-405

Setting an invalid value in the edit form (bigger value than the Long limit) causes a 405 on submit (POST) on tomcat 8.

Same submit on tomcat 7 works as expected and shows a field binding error:

`Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Long for property userId; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "56345345345345345345345345"`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that the reason has to do with the fact that Spring changes the request from POST to PUT based on the hidden field _method (on `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, see [1]) but never changes it back to the previous method. As a result, when there is requested the update form to be shown with the validation or binding error messages, the forward Spring does (`InternalResourceView`), contains the wrapped request which has the method overwritten to PUT and for this reason is rejected by Tomcat >= 8.

A good approach seems to be the use of a manual filter which changes the method to GET on FORWARD [2], [3]

[1] [HTTP Status 405 - JSPs only permit GET POST or HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886941/http-status-405-jsps-only-permit-get-post-or-head)

[2] [405 JSP error with Put Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673041/405-jsp-error-with-put-method)

[3] https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12848

Answer (score 1):

The max value for Long is 9223372036854775807. Your number is bigger than it.
Try `BigDecimal` as parameter or get it as string and then parse it to `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Hi Evgeni, I know that it's bigger. This is why I was expecting a validation error message in my update form (as shown in tomcat 7) instead of a 405 page shown in tomcat 8.
The question is how can I have that validation message on tomcat 8 and why I get a 405 (the request is POST) instead of a validation message.

Comment: @Chris How is your validation organized? Hibernate validator, spring validator, client side? Can you add it to the question.

Comment: there's not any validation constraint on that field. Spring binding mechanism fails to translate the input string to Long and shows the thrown exception message below the fields in a validation error format