# HTTP Put method not working from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, httprequest

I am using Spring Boot to write a simple controller. I am trying Put, Post methods from Postman.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/formData", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processPostFormData() {       
    return "practice/PutPage";
}

@RequestMapping(path="/formData", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public String processPutFormData() {        
    return "practice/PutPage";
}
```

Post works as expected, but Put gives me the following response body:

> "status": 405,
>    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
>    "message": "JSPs only permit GET POST or HEAD"

Also, `csrf().disable()` is set in the subclass of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Are you having POST and PUT in same address at same time? seeing the method name is also same this is propably not the case tho?

Comment: @Clomez same method name is a typo; edited it. I am using Postman; So, there is only one method that can be sent. Can there not be same path for different methods?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886941/http-status-405-jsps-only-permit-get-post-or-head seems same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `method="post"` only but in hidden you can send `_method` as `put` and it works like a charm.I have personally used it for spring framework.

```
<form method="post" ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
...
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form) for more info.

Comment: I am using postman to for my exercise. Also, though _method param can be set, type=hidden cannot be set here. And with just _method=put param pair, the result is still the same.